# Webpack Serve not inserting JS into index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Good day,

I set up Webpack to create an optimized build of my React application to `/dist/` with `webpack --mode production --config webpack.config.production.js` , which automatically inserts the correct initial script into the head of `index.html` ([webpack.config.production.js](https://github.com/realSaddy/CongressLearn/blob/master/client/webpack.config.production.js), [index.html](https://github.com/realSaddy/CongressLearn/blob/master/client/public/index.html)). This works using my Rust back-end to serve the production-built files. However, my script that utilizes `webpack serve --mode development --config webpack.config.js` to enable hot-reloading does not insert the named script into the HTML file, and thus fails to load ([webpack.config.js](https://github.com/realSaddy/CongressLearn/blob/master/client/webpack.config.js)).

I have spent the past hour and a half trying everything I could find to fix this to no avail, and I would greatly appreciate any assistance. Further, if there is a way to utilize my Rust backend with hot-reloading that would be a superior solution :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Robert was on the right track, the problem is that you have two different `publicPath`s in your [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/realSaddy/CongressLearn/blob/master/client/webpack.config.js):

For example, your [output's publicPath](https://github.com/realSaddy/CongressLearn/blob/master/client/webpack.config.js#L28) is `/`:

```js
...
output: {
  filename: "static/[name].[fullhash].js",
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  publicPath: "/",
},
```

while your [devServer's output](https://github.com/realSaddy/CongressLearn/blob/master/client/webpack.config.js#L36) is `http://localhost:3000/dist/`:

```
...
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
  port: 3000,
  publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
  open: true,
},
...
```

Instead, they should be the same path -- in this case, they should be `/` (alternatively, you can remove the `publicPath` property from devServer and it'll work as well):

```js
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
  port: 3000,
  // publicPath: "/",
  open: true,
},
```